# cp: cannot stat on ./startFabric.sh in Docker for Hyperledger Fabric-Writing Yout First Application

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am currently trying to learn Hyperledger Fabric. I have followed all the instructions till [here](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html). I have gotten all the necessary binaries and downloaded all the required samples. When I go into the Fabcar folder and use the "ls" command, I can see all the files expected according to the document EXCEPT chaincode.

```
$ ls
creds/  invoke.js  package.json  query.js  startFabric.sh*
```

When I run "./startFabric.sh" command, I get the following errors:

```
$ ./startFabric.sh
cp: cannot stat '/c/Users/Vaibhav': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Shah/fabric-samples/fabcar/creds/*': No such file or directory
```

I am attaching a screenshot of the entire Docker interface below.

Thank you very much.

[Screenshot of error in Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDxeE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example in https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release/examples/e2e_cli

This is the end-to-end test of the fabric using the command line interface. It helps you understand installation, setting up channels and executing if I recall chaincode_example02. Obviously, this runs on Ubuntu 14.04.

If you are a Windows user, you may want to spin up an Ubuntu 14.04 VM and try out, after installing all the pre-requisites.

Comment: Thank you Mohan. I want to try for Windows and avoid using Ubuntu. But if I cant find a solution to this problem then I definitely look the link above.